# Why can't I copy resp. insert this column into the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am just trying to copy a dataframe column into another dataframe.. but it does not work:

```
df_transf1['timestamp'][0:3]
2018-02-05 14:00:00   2018-02-05 14:00:00
2018-02-05 15:00:00   2018-02-05 15:00:00
2018-02-05 16:00:00   2018-02-05 16:00:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]

X_train1_df['time'] = df_transf1['timestamp'][0:len(X_train1_df)]

type(X_train1_df)
> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

len(X_train1_df)
> 1700

X_train1_df.head()
time    A_phsA
0   NaT 1.679253
1   NaT 1.705401
2   NaT 1.518297
3   NaT 1.229420
4   NaT 1.178687
```

When I try to do it with a numeric column `A_phsA` from df_transf1 it is the same, just with NaNs.
What is wrong?

Comment: have you tried to use df.inser()?

Comment: I didn't know this command. What is the difference?

Comment: it will insert a new column after specific current column with provided data, `DataFrame.insert(self, loc, column, value, allow_duplicates=False)`

Comment: 'X_train1_df.insert(2, "time2", df_transf1['timestamp'][:len(X_train1_df)])' results in NaTs as well.

Comment: I believe this will help you `X_train1_df.insert(2, "time2", df_transf1['timestamp'][:len(X_train1_df)].values)`

Comment: Does 'df_transf1['timestamp'][0:3]' delivers you the data in 2 columns?
What happens if you execute print(df_transf1.head())?
How many 'timestamp' columns do you see?

Comment: @phalanx Yes, that worked, thanks! Why is ',values()' necessary?

Comment: @powerPixie: Thanks for your help as well, I think I will just use the method above :)

Comment: since this worked out for you, i will provide it as an answer with more description so other may use it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since there might be some kind of index mismatch, one way to do this is to convert the column to list, then assign it to another dataframe. conversion will happen with `values`

```
X_train1_df.insert(2, "time2", df_transf1['timestamp'][:len(X_train1_df)].values)
```

for educational purposes you can try it like this:

```
type(df_transf1['timestamp'][:len(X_train1_df)].values)
type(df_transf1['timestamp'][:len(X_train1_df)])
```